# Netbeans 7.x syntax highlighting for .sass files?

Tags: netbeans, sass

Does anyone know of a plugin or method to add syntax highlighting to .sass files in Netbeans 7.x?

This plugin I've found http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/34929/scss-support adds syntax highlighting for .scss, but I need some solution for .sass files.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this plugin which does what I need:

http://code.google.com/p/postcomment/downloads/detail?name=org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm&can=2.

One drawback is that it doesn't allow to customize the syntax colors, but I found a way to do that by editing the following plugin file (you have to unzip the .nbm and .jar files to do that, and then rearchive them using zip without any compression):

`org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-haml.jar/org/netbeans/modules/haml/sass.nbs`

Hope this helps someone else as well

Comment: Thank you for your time to find the solution. I am sorry, but I didn't understand what I have to do. What the meaning of `org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-haml.jar/org/netbeans/modules/haml/sass.nbs`? If it is the path, `org-netbeans-modules-haml.jar` should be the folder, not the file, isn't it? Also, I downloaded `org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm`, but didn't find any `sass.nbs`...

Answer (score 6):

Native support for SASS and LESS [has recently](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeanswebclient/entry/editing_css_preprocessors_sources) been added to the Netbeans codebase - until the next major version (probably 7.4?) is released, you can get it using the current "[development version](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/)".

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately nothing about .sass _extension_ (not .scss) has been told in your link. I see .scss examples only.